# Detect if ViewController presented as FormSheet

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitraitcollection

I have two ViewControllers.

1. Presenting
2. Presented -> can be FullScreen or FormSheet (depending whether it is running on `compact` or `regular` horizontal size class)

How can `Presented` controller detect, whether it is presented as a `modal` or `FormSheet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the `modalPresentationStyle` property of the `UIViewController`.